# Why the screen is getting refreshed when tapping cancel from phone call dialer in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I am just using phone dialer in my swift code it is working fine but I don't know why the screen is getting refreshed when I am tapping on cancel button.

```
if let phoneCallURL = URL(string: "telprompt://1234") {
  let application:UIApplication = UIApplication.shared
  if (application.canOpenURL(phoneCallURL)) {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
      application.open(phoneCallURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    } else {
      // Fallback on earlier versions
      application.openURL(phoneCallURL as URL)
    }
  }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Where you have written this If condition that matters. so, Can you describe more ?

Answer (score 0):

When the phone call action sheet appears, the OS is hanling the interaction, so your app will become inactive, and the `applicationWillResignActive` delegate function will be called.

Once cancel button is taped, your app become active, and you may find some loading code in your `applicationDidBecomeActive` delegate function. You can handle the details in this function.

check [offical document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/managing_your_app_s_life_cycle) to find more details of app life cycle.